# Integration by parts -- applying limits

Tags: calculus

Is the following integration by parts done correctly?

Given that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3x\,\,\,\,\,f(\vec x)=0\\\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3x\,\,\,\,\,\vec xf(\vec x)=0$$
I am trying to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3x\,\,\,\,\,\vec x\cdot \vec x \,\,f(x)$$

So I take $$u=\vec x\cdot \vec x\implies u'=2\vec x\\ v'=f(\vec x)\implies v=\int d^3x\,\,\,f(\vec x)$$

Am I allowed to apply the "limits" to the integral at this stage or must I leave it as indefinite? In other words, can I take $v=0$ thus the whole integral $=[uv]_{limits} -\int\,d^3x\,\,\,u'v=0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $f$ isotropic, i.e. depend only on $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}$?

Comment: @rlgordonma : Not necessarily...

Comment: Think about what you wrote. If you write $v = \int d^3 x f(\vec{x})$, how does the function $v$ depend on its argument?

Comment: @WillieWong : What do you mean?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, which states that $v'(x) = f(x) \implies v(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \mathrm{d}y + C$. Note that $v$'s dependence on $x$ is captured in the "upper limit" of the integral. This works well in 1 dimension. How do you propose your $v$ (now a function of $\mathbb{R}^3$) depend on its argument? Where does the argument come in in the integral on the right hand side? What is $v'$ for $v$ a function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: More precisely, it appears to me that you are trying to ram a vector calculus problem through the integration-by-parts formula of single-variable calculus. **You cannot just do that and hope the notations work out right**. Take a look at [what higher dimensional formulations of integration by parts look like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: The misuse of the single-variable integration-by-parts formula aside, you are also misinterpreting certain things about the question. The expression $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \mathrm{d}^3x f(\vec{x}) = 0$ says that the total integral of $f$ over the entire domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ is zero. The one-dimensional analogue is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$. Note that this says absolutely _nothing_ about the antiderivative of the function $g$. Your conclusion that "$v = 0$" is unjustified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $v$ does not appear to obey $\nabla v = f$.

This is the product fundamental theorem of calculus and the product rule in 3d:

$$\int_S uv \, dS = \int_V u \nabla v + v \nabla u \, dV$$

To construct $v$ such that $\nabla v = f$, you need to use the Green's function for $\nabla$--$G = x/4\pi|x|^3$.  That is,

$$\nabla \int_V G(x-x') f(x') \, dV' = \int_V \delta(x-x') f(x') \, dV' = f(x)$$

This no longer makes it obvious (to me) that $\int_V v \nabla u \, dV$ is zero.